# LESS mixin to use color variable if provided, otherwise use a color function

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, less

I need to extend the Bootstrap 3 Button Variant mixin to take a specific hover color if given.  IE:

```
.button-variant(@color;@background;@border;@hoverColor: false) {
        ...
    &:hover,
    &:focus,
    &:active,
    & .active,
    .open. dropdown-toggle& {
        color: @color;
```

// out of LESS

```
     if (@hoverColor) {
         background-color: @hoverColor;
     }
     else {
         background-color: lighten(@background, 8 % );
         border-color: darken(@border, 12%);
     }
```

// back into LESS

```
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A **guarded mixin** with `iscolor()` would do the job.

(actually, the first example - all the way on top of the http://www.lesscss.org/ page uses this, but further down the page you can also find more on this topic)

So, in your example you could try something in this direction:

```js
.button-variant(@color;@background;@border;@hoverColor: false){
  &:hover,
  &:focus,
  &:active,
  & .active,
  .open .dropdown-toggle {
    color: @color;
```

// all in LESS

```js
    .bg() when (iscolor(@hoverColor)){
      background-color: @hoverColor;
    }
    .bg() when not (iscolor(@hoverColor)){
      background-color: lighten(@background, 8%);
      border-color: darken(@border, 12%);
    }
    .bg();
```

// still in LESS ;-)

```js
  }
}
```

**Test 1:**

```css
test {
  .button-variant(red, green, blue, black);
}
```

returns:

```css
test:hover,
test:focus,
test:active,
test .active,
test .open .dropdown-toggle {
  color: #ff0000;
  background-color: #000000;
}
```

**Test 2:**

```css
test {
  .button-variant(red, green, blue);
}
```

returns:

```css
test:hover,
test:focus,
test:active,
test .active,
test .open .dropdown-toggle {
  color: #ff0000;
  background-color: #00a900;
  border-color: #0000c2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to do this w/o modifying Bootstrap files you can just define new `.button-variant` specialization with additional parameter, e.g.:

```
.button-variant(@color, @background, @border, @hover) {
    // re-use default mixin styles:
    .button-variant(@color, @background, @border);
    // override hover stuff:
    &:hover,
    &:focus,
    &:active,
    &.active,
     .open > .dropdown-toggle& {
        background-color: @hover;
    }
}
```

So the default Bootstrap mixin is used when the mixin is invoked with three arguments and your implementation is used for a four arguments call. (See [Pattern-matching](http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-parametric-feature-pattern-matching) -> args arity example.)

Comment: Thank you, this is pretty handy for I/O tests. Where as @MartinTurjak 's would be better with more complex logic.  

This will come in useful as I rewrite the source for better IE8 only support.